# form submit progress percentage (not ajax)

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, progress, percentage

Is there any way to get live percentage of the form when submitting it? I mean no ajax but when I submit a normal form and specially uploading files with post?

I saw that Chrome is showing the upload progress down left of the browser. How can I have that progress with javascript or jQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. Browsers do not provide an API that gives your JavaScript that information.